# autoreconnect for aiohttp websocket

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am writing an app listening to websocket connections and making infrequent REST requests. aiohttp seems like a natural choice for this, but I'm flexible. The app is simple but needs to be reliable (gigabytes of data to collect daily while minimising data loss).

What is the best way to handle connection loss with aiohttp? I notice that other some other Python libraries have auto reconnect options available. With aiohttp, I could always manually implement this with a loop (start over again as soon as the connection is lost) but I wouldn't know what's the best practice (is it acceptable to keep making reconnection attempts without delay in a loop?).

Answer (score 1):

1. aiohtp is a relative low level library, autoreconnection should be built on top of it.
2. Websocket connection is non-blocking operation in aiohttp.
3. Reliable websocket reconnection is not trivial task. Maybe you need to know what data are received by peer or maybe not -- it depends. In first case you need some high level protocol on top of plain websockets to send acknowledges etc.

Comment: 1) Ok, I could use aiohttp for REST requests and a higher level library for websockets. 3) I can use ping/pong or track sequence numbers, whatever is provided. However my question is what to do any time a loss is detected: it looks like I need to write my own reconnect if I use aiohttp.

Comment: Yes, exactly. aiohttp has no reconnection feature, it is out of scope of the library.